# Jump when pressing a button (unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making my first mobile game but i don't know how i can make a button when pressing it that the player jumps. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && rigidBody.velocity.y == 0)

        {
            rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very straight forward, this should be the easiest way.

1) create a button in Canvas UI

2) create a public "Jump()" function in your "Move2D" class

3) assign this public "Jump()" function on your button event in Canvas UI

```
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Jump()
    {
        rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help!